# flutter encrypt package multi platform unencryption

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

If I encrypt from windows, browser or native, app doesn't decrypt on android.
If I encrypt from linux, chrome browser, app does decrypt succesfully on android.
Do you know how to create functions, encrypt and decrypt, platform independent?

Here the code:

```
String encryptAES(String originalText, Key secretKey) {
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(secretKey, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(originalText, iv: IV.fromLength(16));
  return encrypted.base64;
}

String decryptAES(String encryptedText, Key secretKey) {
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(secretKey, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted = Encrypted.fromBase64(encryptedText);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: IV.fromLength(16));
  return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Post (non-productive) sample data: Plaintext and key, as well as - for the success and failure case - the two ciphertexts. Also post the full code, including function calls, so that the ecodings used become transparent.

Comment: Note that for decryption the *same* IV must be used as for encryption, otherwise decryption will fail. In the current version of the encrypt package (5.0.3), [`IV.fromLength()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/IV/IV.fromLength.html) generates a *random* IV. Your code therefore generates *different* IVs during encryption and decryption, so that decryption generally provides a corrupted plaintext or even fails.

Comment: In older versions of the *encrypt* package (e.g. 4.x), [`IV.fromLength()`](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/blob/4.x/lib/src/encrypted.dart#L59) generates an IV consisting of 0x00 only. Your code would therefore produce the *same* IV (i.e. a zero vector) for encryption and decryption, so that decryption would be successful. Maybe you are using different versions of the encrypt package in your two environments, which could explain your issue.

Comment: Note that usually a random IV is generated during encryption. This is not secret and is passed to the decrypting side together with the ciphertext, typically concatenated. In this way, both ciphertext and IV are available on the decrypting side. You should modify your code accordingly. Eliminating this vulnerability will presumably solve your issue as well.

Comment: I am using the same package version on all platforms, 5.0.1

Comment: `IV.fromLength()` in v5.0.1 creates a zero IV, so your code applies the *same* IV for encryption and decryption. Thus, decryption should work (although a static IV is a vulnerability and a random IV should be used instead, as explained above). Unfortunately, the information you have posted so far is not sufficient to answer this question. Please provide the missing data and code (see my first comment).

Answer (score 0):

The `IV.fromLength()` method generates random values on windows, it generates static values on linux and android, the same version 5.0.1 .

Comment: The breaking change in the implementation of `IV.fromLength()` seems to have taken place from 5.0.1 (filling with 0x00 values) to 5.0.2 (filling with random values), see also issue [#314](https://github.com/leocavalcante/encrypt/issues/314). However, if it is true that `IV.fromLength()` behaves differently on various platforms even for the **same** version (namely 5.0.1), there seems to be an additional problem. You could add this in the thread for #314.